# Boundary between Lexer and Parser

Tags: parsing, lexer, compiler-construction

I'm working on a pet project and I have to implement a lexer/parser. I'm reading about the subject and prototyping a simple math parser to understand as I go along.

There is something I still don't understand quite right, and it's the boundary between the lexer and the parser. Consider the following syntactically wrong expression:

```
+1.234.2 + pi
```

I'm currently lexing this into the following:

```
UnaryPlusOperatorToken: Lexeme "+" Pos: 1
NumberToken: Lexeme "1.234.2" Pos: 2
TriviaToken: Lexeme " " Pos: 9
BinaryAddToken: Lexeme "+" Pos: 10
TriviaToken: Lexeme " " Pos: 11
ConstantToken. Lexeme "pi" Pos: 12
```

Ok, so a couple of things here:

1. Should the lexer really care about the erroneous extra decimal period in the `NumberToken` and add an error to the "error bag" I'm threading through the whole parsing context or should it be the parser that catches this later on?
2. Should the lexer distinguish '+' being a unary operator in one context or a binary operator in another? Or should it simply generate a `PlusToken` and then let the parser figure out what it is?

I'm finding it rather hard to understand where the limit between both is.

Comment: IMHO 1. NumberToken should be "1.234" followed by an "InvalidToken: `.`" 2. Interpretation is a job for the parser.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it:

> Should the lexer really care about the erroneous extra decimal period in the NumberToken and add an error to the "error bag" I'm threading through the whole parsing context or should it be the parser that catches this later on?

Let's see what your options are and compare the pros and cons:

- If you stop scanning at the second decimal, your parser will get the following two tokens: `1.234` `.2` and will have to issue an error like "unexpected token".
- If the lexer scans `1.234.2` as a single token, you'll be easily able to issue an error like "invalid number".

The second choice will issue a much better error message, and is as easy to implement as the first choice, so I'd say it's the better solution. You have an invalid token here, treat it as such.

> Should the lexer distinguish '+' being a unary operator in one context or a binary operator in another? Or should it simply generate a PlusToken and then let the parser figure out what it is?

Nope. The lexer should just output a `+` token. It's the parser's role to further interpret that token's meaning in the context of a *parser rule*.

---

The limit between the lexer and parser can be quite fuzzy at times. While some concerns could easily go on either side without any problems, others will bite you later if you make the wrong call, so it's worth being extra careful while making design choices.

Comment: Thanks! Should I understand then that the lexer shouldn't be adding errors to the parsing context at all and let the parser do that job later on?

Comment: The lexer can certainly issue errors, but these errors will mostly be of the "malformed token" kind. Errors like "this token doesn't belong here" are best left for the parser to deal with. But again, it depends. For instance, suppose you want to forbid expressions like `4--2` (instead of allowing them to be parsed like `4-(-2)`), it may be easier to deal with the token sequence `-` `-` from the lexer directly, but that depends on your implementation.